# expand the menu for web help generated by madcap

Tags: javascript, html, madcap

I know this might be a long shot but i have been Google and reading the javascript code generated for days now without any result.

I'm looking to have the menu expand for the web help generated by madcap when you going directly to a specific subject in the help by a link. This seems to work fine if you use the tool provided by madcap but if you look at the page in a web browser the menu don't expand.

The javascript code is over 10 000  lines of code so skipped to post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a answer how to change the javascript to get this to work but i did find a option in the generation to solve this.

”You can customize your output so that users can always see where the current topic belongs in the table of contents (TOC), even if they did not access the topic via the TOC. This can be done by selecting the "Automatically Synchronize TOC" option in the Skin Editor. When users navigate from topic to topic in the output, the TOC automatically changes accordingly, highlighting the topic that is open.”